# Angular 2 (5) Testbed no provider for MyService

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am having an issue testing angular components. I have looked at several stack overflow posts and I am still stuck.

No matter what I try I keep getting the following error in jasmine:

> Error: StaticInjectorError[RestApiService]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for RestApiService!

Here are a few code snippets:

My component class:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'book-form',
    templateUrl: './book-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./book-form.component.css'],
    providers: [
        RestApiService
    ]
})
export class BookFormComponent implements OnInit {
    model = new Book(1, '', '', '', '');
    severities: Observable<KeyValue[]>;

    constructor(private restApiService: RestApiService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.severities = this.restApiService.getSeverities();
    }
}
```

My mock service:

```
export class RestApiSeviceSpy {

    getSeverities(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of('some data');
    }

    getAssets(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of('some data');
    }
}
```

My beforeEach method (after modification):

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [BookFormComponent],
        providers: [{ provide: RestApiService, useClass: RestApiSeviceSpy }],
        imports: [
            MatDatepickerModule,
            MatNativeDateModule,
            MatFormFieldModule,
            MatInputModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            NoopAnimationsModule],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
        .compileComponents().then(() => {
            let service = TestBed.get(RestApiService);
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookFormComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
}));
```

Any insight into how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**

Here is my service code. I also edited out the bad copy of the @Injectable() above.

```
@Injectable()
export class RestApiService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    getSeverities(): Observable<KeyValue[]> {
        return this.http.get('/api/RiskApi/GetSeverities').map(r => <KeyValue[]>r.json());
    }

    getAssets(): Observable<ApiAsset[]> {
        return this.http.get('/api/RiskApi/GetAssets').map(r => <ApiAsset[]>r.json());
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I updated the code above to show current beforeEach and to show the updated spy/mock class.

**Edit**
Here is the output from the test run:

<kbd>karma start --run-once</kbd>

`01 03 2018 17:02:58.196:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
01 03 2018 17:02:58.226:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
01 03 2018 17:02:58.227:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
01 03 2018 17:02:58.231:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
01 03 2018 17:02:58.963:INFO [Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket lxAY8w15N_373BOwAAAA with id 41860275
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0) BookFormComponent should create FAILED
        Error: StaticInjectorError[RestApiService]:
          NullInjectorError: No provider for RestApiService!
            at _NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1033:19)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 3 of 4 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0) BookFormComponent should create FAILED
        Error: StaticInjectorError[RestApiService]:
          NullInjectorError: No provider for RestApiService!
            at _NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1033:19)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0) BookFormComponent should create FAILED
        Failed: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9876/api/RiskApi/GetSeverities
            at stack (node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2455:17)
        [object ErrorEvent] thrown
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0) BookFormComponent should create FAILED
        Failed: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:9876/api/RiskApi/GetSeverities
            at stack (node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2455:17)
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (2 FAILED) (0.311 secs / 0 secs)`

Comment: why do you have `@Injectable()
@Component` right after each other ? also, can you post your service ?

Comment: The Injectable and Component were a bad copy from my code

Comment: I just discovered that Nadhir's suggestions worked. My problem was that a different test made it look like my component test was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line:
`let spy: RestApiSeviceSpy = new RestApiSeviceSpy([], []);`

now in your testbed:

```
providers:[ {provide: RestApiService,useClass: RestApiSeviceSpy}]//After you import your spy
```

Now for your mock/spy, you don't have to extend it with the real service.
Just create a service that takes the same dependencies and returns some fake data that's all. like so:

```
export class RestApiSeviceSpy {

        getSeverities(): Observable<any> {
            return Observable.of('some data');
        }

        getAssets(): Observable<any> {
            return Observable.of('some data');
        }
    }
```

And your spec:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [BookFormComponent],
        providers: [{ provide: RestApiService, useValue: spy }],
        imports: [
            MatDatepickerModule,
            MatNativeDateModule,
            MatFormFieldModule,
            MatInputModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            NoopAnimationsModule],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderEntryComponent);
       component = fixture.componentInstance;

}));
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but it still doesn't work.

Here are the relevant lines:

 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [BookFormComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: RestApiService, useClass: RestApiSeviceSpy }],
...

 .overrideComponent(BookFormComponent, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        { provide: RestApiService, useClass: RestApiSeviceSpy }
                    ]
                }
            })

Comment: @James I updated my answer. try delete all the `.overrideProvider .overrideComponent` parts

Comment: I didn't notice this before, but I was getting the error twice. Now I get it once, and then it looks like the service I am trying to replace is constructed and the http calls are placed (unsuccessfully since I am running the tests from karma and the backend services are not running). I'm not sure if the version matters, but I am using 5.2.3.

Comment: Alright, in your spy service delete the whole constructor, check my updated answer

Comment: I updated the code above to reflect the current status. I am still getting the error.

Comment: why don't you add the service to your module and delete it from your component ?

Comment: I had it that way to begin with and it didn't work. I just put it back in the module with the same result.

Comment: This is a solid answer. However, it's important to note that while using fake classes is a common approach in Angular, it has it's downsides. With this approach you lose the type-safe connection to the real service in your spec.

I'd recommend using something like `ts-mocks` to mock out services. You'll avoid writing duplicate mock-services and you'll keep type-safety so if your service contract changes, your test will fail to compile until you fix it.